# VueJS + Webpack Dev Server not able to hot reload url subpaths

Tags: vue.js, webpack, webpack-dev-server

My application runs on the subdirectory http://localhost:8080/admin_suffix

`suffix` is a ENV variable which I can change and define in a .env file.

Once i run the webpack dev server, accessing `http://localhost:8080/admin_suffix` works.

Clicking on the hyperlinks in the SPA which points other subpaths works too. For example, I can navigate to `http://localhost:8080/admin_suffix/subdirectory`

However, when i hit reload on `http://localhost:8080/admin_suffix/subdirectory`, i will get an error "Cannot GET /admin_suffix/subdirectory"

I also cannot enter the subpath into the browser directly to load the page. Only ``http://localhost:8080/admin_suffix` works.

My configuration are as follows:

webpack.base.config.js:

```
  entry: {
    main: './src/main',
    vendors: './src/vendors'
  },
  devServer: {
        host: '0.0.0.0',
        disableHostCheck: true
  },
  output: {
    path: path.join(__dirname, '../dist')
  }
```

webpack.dev.config.js:

```
module.exports = merge(webpackBaseConfig, {
  output: {
    publicPath: '/',
    filename: '[name].js',
    chunkFilename: '[name].chunk.js'
  }
});
```

src/main.js:

```
const RouterConfig = {
    mode: 'history',
    routes: Routers,
    base: '/admin_suffix/'
}
```

Comment: You are using Vue in 'history' mode. Did you completely follow all the steps from their documentation? See here: https://router.vuejs.org/guide/essentials/history-mode.html

Answer (score 4):

Enable [`devServer.historyApiFallback`](https://webpack.js.org/configuration/dev-server/#devserver-historyapifallback) in `webpack.base.config.js`:

```
devServer: {
  historyApiFallback: true,
  // ...
},
```

This configures `webpack-dev-server` to fallback to `index.html` when the route is not found (`404`).

The Vue app and router are initialized from the main page (`index.html`), so refreshing the page while on a subroute would normally result in a `404` because the router would not have been setup yet. However, the fallback configuration mentioned above would result in the `index.html` being served instead, allowing the router to be setup and the subroute to subsequently complete.